# Getting Error in version defining in solidity inside vscode

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I used hardhat to install solidity setup while declaring the version I want to use of solidity. I'm still getting an error

```
***pragma solidity ^0.8.0;***

contract Transaction {
uint256 transactionCounter;

event Transfer(address from, address receiver, uint amount, string message, uint256 timestamp, string keyword);

struct TransferStruct {
    address sender;
    address receiver;
    uint amout;
    string message;
    uint256 timestamp;
    string keyword;
}
```

even I have mentioned model 0.8.4 in hardhat.config.js file to

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

for (const account of accounts) {
console.log(account.address);
}
});
module.exports = {
 solidity: "0.8.4",
};
```

can someone please help me with this

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I solved it, but thank you for support

Comment: Great. :) Please consider posting an answer to your own question with description how you solved it, so that others with the same issue are able to solve it easier.